# javascript store image to array not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to generate some images on a server, store them to an array in javascript and use them dynamically.

I'm doing this by the following code snippet:

```
imageArray = new Array();
for(var i=1; i<=51; i++){
    imageArray[i] = new Image();
    if(i<10){
        imageArray[i].src = "<?php echo 'tmp/'.$_SESSION['token'].'/out';?>0" + i + ".bmp";
    }else{
        imageArray[i].src = "<?php echo 'tmp/'.$_SESSION['token'].'/out';?>" + i + ".bmp";
    }
}
```

Later I load them as background images in javascript.

```
for (var i = -3; i <= 3; i++) {
    var img = $('#imgdiv' + i).get(0);
    if (imageArray[+i + +image0] != undefined) {
        img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imageArray[+i + +image0].src + ')';
    } else {
        img.style.backgroundImage = '';
    }
}
```

this is working in firefox, but in chrome every time I set the background image it is loading the image from the server.

Is there another way to store them, because I'd like to delete them after the page has loaded?

Comment: Might be related to caching. Try sending your image with cache-related headers so to make clear to the client (browser), that there is no need to re-load the image. Other than that it might be possible that Chrome lives its own life when it comes to caching background images, although my general experience is the opposite: that it does **not** reload background images as i would normally want it to.

Comment: you just need path to image not all this src stuff - so then the array is just the path to each image.

Comment: storing the path to the image in an array does not mean it will store the actual images in that array

Comment: Thak you. But how can l store an image in JavaScript? Because I generate them on the server and will not need them anymore.